# Prove that 'lines are parallel if they don't intersect' with a suitable diagram

Tags: geometry

It's obvious that if 2 lines don't intersect they are parallel but how do you prove it? We have been taught how to prove 2 lines are parallel by proving that their complementary angles, alternate interior angles etc. are equal but I can't find a way to do that in this question.

Comment: Can you show, assuming they aren't parallel (by your definition relying on complementary angles), that they must intersect?

Comment: @JonathanY. I could prove that if the lines aren't parallel then their co -interior angles would not add up to 180 which would mean that they would intersect.

Comment: $g$ and $h$ are parallel iff the number of their common points doesn't equal $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "If 2 lines don't intersect, then they are parallel" has contrapositive "If two lines are not parallel, then they intersect".

Given two lines, draw a line crossing both.  Since the lines are not parallel, the two angles on one side of the new line must add up to less than $180$.  Now you can use the [parallel postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) to conclude that the two lines meet on that side.

Comment: Do you think that the law of sines is admissible in this context?  I'd be more willing to use point slope form to find the exact intersection point of two given lines.  But even that seems unlike what Mayank is looking for.

Comment: Ok.  I imagine an appeal to the parallel postulate is exactly what this question deserves.

Comment: Thanks! The parallel postulate is also what we have just been taught.

Answer (score 2):

You do not prove this because this is a definition. Have a look at Euclid's Elements, a true beauty from 300 BC. Significant part of high school geometry is copy-paste from Elements (maybe without putting proper references to this book). Copies in Greek survived 2300+ years.

Definitions from Book 1:

> 23. Parallel straight lines are straight lines which, being in the same plane and being produced indefinitely in both directions, do not meet one another in either direction. [Euclid. Elements (with folio images!) at http://www.claymath.org](http://www.claymath.org/euclid/index/book-1-definitions)